# Limiting the size of a HTTP post request on JBoss

Tags: java, http, tomcat, jboss

I am using Jboss 4.2.3 as an appserver. Is there a way to limit the size of the HTTP Post request accepted by JBoss? I want to limit the size to avoid DOS attacks.

I already sat maxHttpHeaderSize and maxPostSize in the server.xml, but neither of them seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 2):

`maxPostSize` defines how big a POST can get before Tomcat will "automatically" parse it, whatever that means.

If you're doing this for security reasons, you need to think twice about how you do it. A DOS attack isn't going to conveniently announce its size as an HTTP request header, it's just going to send data until your server falls over.

You *could* check the `Content-Length` header of the request, and reject it immediately if it's not present, or too big, but you run the risk of rejecting genuine clients that don't supply the header, which many won't.

Otherwise, you're just going to have to read the request data until it crosses a threshold, and *then* reject it.

Either way, the container can't help you much.

Comment: +1 and a DDOS attack is not only sending large data. It's also a happening of thousands of simultaneous requests at once.

Answer (score 2):

For Jboss you should configure in configuration file (eg: standalone-full.xml) like this:
with **max-post-size="26214400"** means 25MB

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:3.1">
        <buffer-cache name="default"/>
        <server name="default-server">
            <http-listener name="default" max-post-size="26214400" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https"/>
            <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
            </host>
        </server>
        <servlet-container name="default">
            <jsp-config/>
            <websockets/>
        </servlet-container>
        <handlers>
            <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
        </handlers>
        <filters>
            <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="JBoss-EAP/7"/>
            <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1"/>
        </filters>
    </subsystem>
```

Comment: this is correct for WildFly, not for JBoss classic.

Comment: Thanks @jwenting for your feedback. I'm running jboss-eap-7 standalone mode and it works, and for domain mode I have to set max-post-size for ajp-listener. Can you enlight me please?

Comment: EAP7 is the commercial version of Wildfly :) Classic is JBoss4 (and maybe 5), which have a completely different architecture. They're also very old (think 10+ years) but still in use.

Comment: Thanks @jwenting again for this info. For this old version, we should look into the manual or the source code directly.

Comment: Which is what the other 2 answers did 10 years ago :)

Answer (score 0):

Lets say we have the a default standalone configuration settings of undertow module which sets max-post-size to 10mb. Documentation on [RedHat](https://access.redhat.com/webassets/avalon/d/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.4/mgmt_model/subsystem/undertow/server/http-listener/index.html).

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:12.0" default-virtual-host="default-host" statistics-enabled="true">
            <buffer-cache name="default"/>
            <server name="default-server" default-host="default-host">
                <http-listener name="http" socket-binding="http" max-parameters="20000" allow-unescaped-characters-in-url="true" proxy-address-forwarding="true" enable-http2="true"/>
                <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                    <filter-ref name="samesite-cookie"/>
                    <filter-ref name="hsts-header"/>
                    <filter-ref name="x-frame-options"/>
                    <filter-ref name="x-xss-protection"/>
                    <filter-ref name="x-content-type-options"/>
                    <filter-ref name="gzipfilter"/>
                    <http-invoker security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
                </host>
            </server>
...
```

To change the max-post-size variable to whatever variable is desire we can connect to JBOSS CLI and execute the following command to update the configuration. If you do not know how to connect to JBOSS CLI, [here is the official documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.2/html/management_cli_guide/getting_started_management_cli#:%7E:text=2.1.-,Launch%20the%20Management%20CLI,script%20provided%20with%20JBoss%20EAP.&text=For%20Windows%20Server%2C%20use%20the,to%20launch%20the%20management%20CLI.).

```
/subsystem="undertow"/server="default-server"/http-listener="http":write-attribute(name=max-post-size,value=11534336)
```

Once the command is executed your standalone configuration should look like that:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:12.0" default-virtual-host="default-host" statistics-enabled="true">
            <buffer-cache name="default"/>
            <server name="default-server" default-host="default-host">
                <http-listener name="http" socket-binding="http" max-post-size="11534336" max-parameters="20000" allow-unescaped-characters-in-url="true" proxy-address-forwarding="true" enable-http2="true"/>
                <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                    <filter-ref name="samesite-cookie"/>
                    <filter-ref name="hsts-header"/>
                    <filter-ref name="x-frame-options"/>
                    <filter-ref name="x-xss-protection"/>
                    <filter-ref name="x-content-type-options"/>
                    <filter-ref name="gzipfilter"/>
                    <http-invoker security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
                </host>
            </server>
...
```

This means that now the max-post-size is set to 11mb.